# Checkpointing with Spring AWS Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, amazon-kinesis, spring-integration-aws

According to Spring release notes, `spring-integration-aws.1.1.0.M1` does not include DynamoDB MetaDataStore implementation. There is still `ConcurrentMetadataStore` class which is a key-value based store and based on implementation I suppose it maps streams with latest sequence number read. But it does not use any data store as to retrieve checkpoints.

I am using spring integration for kinesis consuming and need to implement checkpointing. I am wondering if I need to do it manually by connecting to DynamoDB and always update checkpoints or there is another way of doing it using spring framework?

P.S: I can't use Spring Cloud KinesisBinderConfiguration as I dynamically consume events from a list of configurable streams.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not talking about Spring Cloud Stream and the AWS Kinesis Binder implementation,  then I don't see any blockers for you to upgrade your solution to the Spring Integration AWS `2.0` and go ahead with already provided `DynamoDbMetaDataStore`.

Or if that is so hard for you to move to the Spring Integration `5.0`, then you simply can consider to copy/paste an implementation to your own class and inject it into the `KinesisMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/aws/metadata/DynamoDbMetaDataStore.java

Although it is really available in the `1.1.0.RELEASE` - I don't see reason for your to stick with the `1.1.0.M1`: https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/27/spring-integration-for-aws-1-1-ga-available

Comment: How did I miss that! updated to Spring Integration AWS 2.0. Thanks Artem